# How to console.log a List of results from SOQL

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql

Apex

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Object__c> getLocation() {
    return [
        SELECT Location.a__c, Location.b__c, Location.c__c,  Location.d__c
        FROM Object__c
        WHERE Object__c.Id = 'zzz1123'
    ];
}
```

JS

```
  location;
  getLocation() 
    .then(result=>{
        this.location = result;
        console.log('locations data: ' + this.location);
        })
  ...
```

In the console.log I get [object Object], instead of the values and fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use string concatenation, you'll end up with `[object Object]`, and using `JSON.stringify` gives you a long mess of JSON. The recommended approach is to use `console.log` and pass in the entire object without converting to a string. You can give console.log multiple parameters separated by commas:

```
console.log('locations data', this.location)
```

Your browser's console should give you an arrow dropdown so you can explore the data with your mouse, complete with highlights (blue for numbers, purple for properties, brown for strings, etc).

Comment: @ApexCowboy If it's Proxy data, just look in the `[[Target]]` dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "serialize" the object to be able to print it as a string. `JSON.stringify()` is one such way to do that

e.x.

```
console.log('locations data: ' + JSON.stringify(this.location));
```

Comment: `console.log('locations data', this.location)` reads *much* nicer than this suggestion. If you haven't used it, give it a try sometime.